# Relationships between schema in mongoose and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm developing a chat application where users can have private conversations. I'm using nodejs along with socketio and mongodb. I need to have some relationships between some schema like chat and thread schema, where a chat schema consist of a thread(id or name). The Thread schema is there for retrieving conversations easily.I found some answers related to relationships between models in mongoose but im not quite sure how it works. This is the code that I've tried. How to create this kind of a relationship?.

```
const message = new Schema({
    sender:{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'user'
    },
    message:String,
    thread:{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'thread'
    },
    created:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Thread schema

```
 const thread = new Schema({
    people:[{uname:String}],
    created:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

User schema

```
const User = new Schema({
  fname:String,
  lname:String,
  uname:{type:String,unique:true},
  email:{type:String,unique:true,lowercase:true},
  password:String,
  friends:[{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User'
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called population in mongoose, you can populate this fields from other collections:

```
...
User.findOne({fname: 'John'})
.populate('friends')
.exec()
.then(user=>{
    console.log('User - ', user);
})
.catch(err=>{
   throw err;
})
```